# Get width of a given text as length

Tags: calculations, lengths

Is there a TeX command that returns the width of a given text as *length* value, so that I can use the result directly as a length argument of another command?

I mean, I would like to have a command `\getWidth{my text}` and want to use the result directly as the first argument of `\parbox`:

```
\parbox{\getWidth{my text}}{my foo\\bar text}
```

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Use the `calc` package (`\usepackage{calc}`):

```
\parbox{\widthof{my text}}{...}
```

An “only primitives” approach would be

```
\newdimen\mywidth
\setbox0=\hbox{<text to measure>}
\mywidth=\wd0
```

and then use `\mywidth`.

Comment: I think `calc` package may redefine some units. For example, I get an error using math unit `mu` when the package is loaded.

Comment: @M.Reza `mu` can be used only in math and only for `\mkern` or `\mskip`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am trying to use this with `textpos` to specify width for the `textblock`, but it seems like the with returned by `\widthof` can not be taken by `textblock`, with error showing **Missing number, treated as zero**.

Comment: @zyy `\widthof` returns a suitable result only in some places, one of which is the argument to `\parbox`. Unfortunately `textpos` cannot use it, as far as I know.

Comment: @egreg Thanks! I will look for something else.

Comment: @zyy One usually does something like `\settowidth{\dimen0}{<text>}` and then passes `\dimen0` to the macro that has to use the width.

Comment: @egreg I found out why, `textblock` takes in a relative value with no units while `\widthof` returns with a unit, this is explained in the documentation of `textpos` where it talks about troubleshooting **Missing number, treated as zero**.

Comment: @zyy Oh, yes. I tried `textblock` quite a long time ago; there is `textpos*` that accepts lengths, AFAIR.

Comment: He asked for a TeX command, loading the calc package is not possible in all macro packages. It does however work with LaTeX

Comment: @M0M0 What do you mean? The question has `\parbox` that looks LaTeX to me. I modified the answer, so you can retract your undeserved downvote.

Comment: @egreg Sorry for the downvote and thanks for the edit. I was looking for an answer and google kept leading me to LaTeX-only solutions... I changed my downvote to an upvote :)

Answer (score 163):

I like to answer the question in a more general way, so that it is useful to a wider group of people.

There are the following macros which allow to store the width, height (the material above the baseline) and depth (the material below the baseline) of a given content.

```
\settowidth{\somelength}{<content>}
\settodepth{\somelength}{<content>}
\settoheight{\somelength}{<content>}
```

The `calc` package also provides one for the total height (height + depth):

```
\settototalheight{\somelength}{<content>}
```

as well as

```
\widthof{<content>}
\heightof{<content>}
\depthof{<content>}
\totalheightof{<content>}
```

which can be used directly inside `\setlength` or `\addtolength`.

If you need multiple dimension of the same content you can also store it in a box register and use its dimension directly (the above macros do this as well internally). These are dimension expressions and can be prefixed with a factor, e.g. `.5\wd\mybox` is half the width.

```
\newsavebox\mybox
\sbox{\mybox}{<content>}
\wd\mybox % width
\ht\mybox % height
\dp\mybox % depth
```

For the totalheight you need to add `\ht\mybox` and `\dp\mybox` together.

Comment: How do you automate the addition of these two values together?

Comment: @kando: You can use additions inside `\setlength` when you load the `calc` package.

Comment: There is also some useful related information here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52861/what-is-the-plain-tex-equivalent-of-settowidth

Answer (score 116):

This can be done *without* the `calc` package

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
  \newlength{\myl}
  \settowidth{\myl}{test text}
  \the\myl
\end{document}
```

`\the\myl` will print out the value ~37pt.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an option with `pgf`

```latex
% !Mode:: "TeX:UTF-8"
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\pgfmathwidth{"length you wanted"}
\parbox{\pgfmathresult pt}{the text you want to print out}
\end{document}
```

where `\pgfmathwidth` returns width of the text contained in the double quotes to `\pgfmathresult`, notice the result of `\pgfmathwidth` is always in **points** and **only the numeric value** is provided

[image: parbox]

By the way, `\pgfmathwidth` works for Chinese characters as well.