# How to use \widthof as parameter to \kern

Tags: calculations, lengths, kerning

I sometimes encounter a problem when I attempt to use `\widthof` from the `calc` package, and don't know why.  In the past I have just worked around it using a two step process of defining a `\newdimen{}` and using `\settowidth` (or `\setlength` and `\widthof`) to determine the value before attempting to use this length.

The MWE below shows how this fails when I attempt to use the `\widthof` as the length of a `\kern` (i.e., the `\KernA` macro), but the two step process works just fine:

[image]

## Questions:

1. Why does `\KernA` not work?
2. When can I use `\widthof` directly?

### References:

- [Get width of a given text as length](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18576/get-width-of-a-given-text-as-length)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand*{\KernA}{\kern\widthof{$text$}}%

\newdimen{\KernAmount}%
\newcommand*{\KernB}{%
    \setlength{\KernAmount}{\widthof{$text$}}%
    \kern\KernAmount%
}%

\newcommand*{\KernC}{%
    \settowidth{\KernAmount}{$text$}%
    \kern\KernAmount%
}%


\begin{document}
x~$text$~y 

%x~\KernA~y  \verb|\kernA: \widthof| ??

x~\KernB~y  \verb|\KernB: \setlength and \widthof|

x~\KernC~y  \verb|\KernC: \settowidth|
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could just use `\hphantom{$text$}` instead.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Yes that would be a simpler solution for this situation in the MWE, but this was meant to be a more general question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`\kern` is a TeX primitive which awaits a dimension expression, while `\widthof` is a `calc` package function which only works in `\setlength` and friends. It requires internal box assignments, which are not allowed in a normal dimension expression. You can't therefore use `\widthof` and other things like this at positions where TeX dimension expressions are awaited. You need to use `\setlength` first to assign the value to a length register and then use this register, as you did.

Answer (score 8):

The problem here is that `\widthof` is actually only a "macro" that works inside one of [`calc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/calc)'s redefined length macros. Using `\show\widthof` you'll note that it is actually defined as `\ignorespaces`... a placeholder and action to remove any preceding spaces in the argument. As such, your two-step procedure (using an interim length) is required to obtain the desired result.

The alternative `\settowidth` macro does box assignment and length extraction using (from [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx)):

```
\def\@settodim#1#2#3{\setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{{#3}}#2#1\@tempboxa
       \setbox\@tempboxa\box\voidb@x}
\def\settoheight{\@settodim\ht}
\def\settodepth {\@settodim\dp}
\def\settowidth {\@settodim\wd}
```

Comment: The calc package redefines `\setcounter`, `\addtocounter`, `\setlength` and `\addtolength` to benefit from the extended syntax. Only in their arguments `\widthof` and the similar commands receive the meaning for doing computations; outside of them they are equivalent, as you say, to `\ignorespaces`.