# Passing length in form of a string instead of measure

Tags: lengths, strings

I'd like to pass a measure of length in form of a string, i.e.

```
\setlength{string}
```

or

```
\setlength{'string'}
```

instead of

```
\setlength{2.5cm}
```

I seem to remember seeing something like that somewhere in LaTeX, but can't find it. Appreciate your input!

Comment: Are you looking for `\settowidth{\somelength}{string}`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Get width of a given text as length](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18576/5764)

Comment: 1 minute. I love StackExchange. @egreg Wonderful, thanks a lot!  I'd mark it as the answer, but I can't do that with a comment. Werner - it's not the exact same issue, though I see your point.

Comment: @Zubo: Questions are phrased differently, but they use the same principles. The other is actually a little more comprehensive than this request, making this one a subset of the linked post (in my opinion). I'm voting to close as a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The LaTeX kernel provides

```
\settowidth
\settoheight
\settodepth
```

and you probably want the first one:

```
\newlength{\somelength}

\settowidth{\somelength}{some text}
```

Note that it's better to set lengths to a text dependent width after `\begin{document}`. So, if you need `\somelength` for a macro definition in the preamble, you should do

```
\newcommand{\foo}{...depending on \somelenght...}

\AtBeginDocument{\settowidth{\somelength}{some text}}
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the detailed explanation!