# Need the height of the descent

Tags: fonts, height

I'm creating a few custom icons for my latex documents that are repeated using tikz.

However, in order to align them to the text I need to know the descent to set the baseline in the correct place. I also want the descent to be calculated depending on font size.

[image: the measures needed]
I might need other measures from that picture too.

Here is one example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\increasing}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0]
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (1ex,1em);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
f \increasing
\end{document}
```

I want the arrow to be lower, so I need to set baseline=descent in the tikzpicture. How can I do that?
Any documentation of the rest of the heights?

Comment: would https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366558/biggest-depth-of-a-character-in-a-string maybe help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this??  I set the baseline to the depth of the `g` descender and the top of the arrow to the height of the `X`, using the active font size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\increasing}{%
\setbox0=\hbox{Xg}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=\dp0]
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (1ex,\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\Large fg\increasing
\normalsize fg\increasing
\tiny fg\increasing
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't mention before, but I would like the figure to scale when using different font sizes like \Large. I believe this measures the descent of a normal g always.

Comment: @mendus I edited to measure the current font size

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes it would be nice to add a g too next to f. (+1)

Comment: @koleygr Done, per request.

Comment: Perfect ! (I will create a second account to upvote again :P )

Comment: @koleygr Now, now, now, let's not be a Democrat!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes It looks fine now, the result is what I was looking for, so I'll accept the answer.
Anyway, I wonder if creating the dummy box can be avoided, and inquire the current font about those values.

Answer (score 7):

You can measure the maximum descender:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\showbaseline}{%
  \settodepth{\alphabetdepth}{fgjpqy}
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\vrule width 5cm height -\alphabetdepth depth \dimexpr\alphabetdepth+0.1pt\relax}%
  \ignorespaces
}

\newlength{\alphabetdepth}
\newcommand{\increasing}{%
  \settodepth{\alphabetdepth}{fgjpqy}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=\alphabetdepth]
  \draw[->] (0,0) -- (1ex,1em);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}

\showbaseline
f \increasing\quad {g \increasing} {\itshape f \increasing}

\bigskip

{\LARGE\showbaseline f \increasing\quad g \increasing}

\bigskip

{\tiny \showbaseline\itshape f \increasing}

\end{document}
```

The `\showbaseline` command is just for making clear where the maximum depth is located.

[image]

Comment: Seems similar to the other approach but without creating a box. Works well too.