# Adjusting minipage's width to avoid line breaks

Tags: minipage, box, calc

For `foo` and `baz`, `widthof` return sensible/nonsensible values. When the width of the `minipage` wrapped around `foo` and `baz` is set to these numbers, neither has the desired width, that is, the width of the longest line contained within. In other words, I'm looking to set `minipage`'s width such that no line breaks.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{zebra-goodies}

\newsavebox\foo
\sbox{\foo}{%
  % 3456789
  abcdefgh
  \\abc%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\baz}{}
{%
  % 3456789
  abcdefgh\\% "longest line"
  abc
}

\begin{document}

\noindent \texttt{foo}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37294/112708
\begin{tabular}{ll}
w & \widthof\foo \\
h & \heightof\foo \\
d & \depthof\foo
\end{tabular}

\frame{\begin{minipage}{\widthof{\foo}}
  \usebox{\foo}
\end{minipage}}

{\tiny\todo{adjust mp's width to fit exactly longest line}}

\noindent \texttt{baz}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
w & \widthof\baz \\
h & \heightof\baz \\
d & \depthof\baz
\end{tabular}

\frame{\begin{minipage}{\widthof{\baz}}
  \baz
\end{minipage}}

{\tiny\todo{adjust mp's width to fit exactly longest line}}

\end{document}
```

[image: Shot-1]

Comment: `\frame{\begin{minipage}{\wd\foo}` You want the width of the box and not the width of '\foo', right? For `\baz` put it in a box if you want to measure it.

Comment: Surely I have not understood the problem, but a minipage of the width of longest sentence without  allow line breaks is a simple tabular environment, i.e., `\frame{\begin{tabular}{l}
  \baz
\end{tabular}}`

Comment: I want the `minipage` to contain  `abcdefgh\\abc` and have the width of `abcdefgh` since its the longest. I have the intuition boxes comes into play, just not sure how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a first debugging step, you should look at what's printed with `\usebox{\foo}`, namely

[image]

Why's that? Because `\\` essentially does `\hfill\break` which has no effect whatsoever when building a horizontal box.

If you want to set a length to the widest word in a list, you can use a `tabular`:

```latex
\newcommand{\settowidest}[2]{% items must be separated by \\
  \settowidth{#1}{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}#2\end{tabular}}%
}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\newcommand{\settowidest}[2]{% items must be separated by \\
  \settowidth{#1}{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}#2\end{tabular}}%
}

\newcommand{\foo}{%
    % 3456789
    abcdefgh\\% "longest line"
    abc%
}

\newlength{\foolen}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \settowidest{\foolen}{\foo}%
}

\begin{document}

\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\foolen}\foo\end{minipage}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, you can avoid all measuring by directly using a `tabular` just like in the definition of `\settowidest`. Or you can use `varwidth` (look for it on the site).