# Cutting text to a given length

Tags: calculations, word-count

I want to put text on the header of my document (I'm using `fancyhdr`), but if the text surpass certain length it overlaps with other elements. For example, if I want to put "A very long text to fit in the header", then the desired output will be "A very long text...". Of course this output depends on a given length.

In [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18576/get-width-of-a-given-text-as-length) there is a method to obtain the length of given text. But I cannot figure out how to display just a few words of the text.

Sorry if I don't have a MWE, but I don't know how to start. I've tried `\clip` the text using `TikZ`but it cuts words, something like: "A very lon..."

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is a package called `truncate` that is able to cut a text after a certain width

Comment: @daleif Ohh nice! That will do the trick. Thanks

Comment: I already did what I want, so you can post your comment as an answer and I’ll mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a rather old package called `truncate`, so one can use

```
\truncate{122pt}{This text has been~truncated}
```

and the text will be truncated before 122pt, between words and never at a `~`.

See the `truncate` package manual for more options