# How to prevent word wrap and new lines in table cells?

Tags: tables, formatting, line-breaking, hyphenation, xltabular

I have a `xltabular` table which is filled via script with data, so I don't really know what length the text has that is put into the table cells. Is there a function or method which can just cut off the text if it is too long to fit in one line?  Here is the example of my table.

```
\documentclass[
fontsize=11pt,
parskip=half,
firstfoot=off,
foldmarks=off
]{scrlttr2}  
%

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{lmodern}  

\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage[textwidth=\useplength{firstfootwidth}]{geometry} %showframe
               
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}    




\begin{document} 

%recipient  
\begin{letter}{ 
Max Muste \\
Teststraße 2    \\
55555 Teststadt \\
Schweiz         \\ 
     }
% 
\opening{}
%
    
{\footnotesize
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{\hskip0pt}r p{3.1cm} X r r r@{\hskip0pt}}

Menge & Artikelnummer & Bezeichnung & WHG & Einzelpreis & Gesamtpreis \\ \hline 
\endfirsthead

Menge & Artikelnummer & Bezeichnung & WHG & Einzelpreis & Gesamtpreis \\ \hline 
\endhead
\hline
\multicolumn{6}{l}{Bla}
\endlastfoot
1 & T-ERICSSON GF768 & Lötzinn bleifrei mit Silber- und Kupferanteil,Ø 1,0 mm, 12,5 g & 0 N & 12,77300 & 12,77\\ *[\fill]
\end{xltabular}
}

\end{letter} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

So basically `mm, 12,5g` should be thrown away, even if it is as text in the cell.

Comment: Shouldn't ",Ø 1,0 mm, 12,5 g" be discarded? The substring ",Ø 1,0", by itself, must surely cause needless confusion.

Comment: @Mico Yes, it will be confusing and outright stupid. But I just want to know if it is possible. The word wrap in itself with the full information is flawless, but I just want to know if it is possible.

Comment: the _only_ thing `tabularx` does compared to a normal table is adjust the target width for linebreaking in X cells, I would never use tabularx for data tables that do not need linebreaking (even though I wrote it)

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/557188/cutting-text-to-a-given-length?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there is not much sense to use an `X` column if you want to do that, an `l` ones will work ok, but one option is to use the [`truncate`](https://texdoc.org/serve/truncate/0) package (although you need a bit of gimmick to automatically apply it to a cell, here I use [`collcell`](https://texdoc.org/serve/collcell/0) package):

```latex
\documentclass[
fontsize=11pt,
parskip=half,
firstfoot=off,
foldmarks=off
]{scrlttr2}
%

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage[textwidth=\useplength{firstfootwidth}]{geometry} %showframe
\usepackage[fit, hyphenate]{truncate}
\usepackage{collcell}
\def\mytruncate{\truncate{6cm}}
\newcolumntype{T}{ >{\collectcell\mytruncate}X<{\endcollectcell} }

\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}

%recipient
\begin{letter}{
Max Muste \\
Teststraße 2    \\
55555 Teststadt \\
Schweiz         \\
     }
%
\opening{}

%
{\footnotesize
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{\hskip0pt}r p{3.1cm} T r r r@{\hskip0pt}}

Menge & Artikelnummer & Bezeichnung & WHG & Einzelpreis & Gesamtpreis \\ \hline
\endfirsthead

Menge & Artikelnummer & Bezeichnung & WHG & Einzelpreis & Gesamtpreis \\ \hline
\endhead
\hline
\multicolumn{6}{l}{Bla}
\endlastfoot
1 & T-ERICSSON GF768 & Lötzinn bleifrei mit Silber- und Kupferanteil,Ø 1,0 mm, 12,5 g & 0 N & 12,77300 & 12,77\\ *[\fill]
\end{xltabular}
}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thx @Rmano, how can I redifine the Marker if I just want a whitespace? I tried it according to the doc with \TruncateMarker(\renewcommand{\TruncateMarker}{}) but I get an error.

Comment: It's `\renewcommand\TruncateMarker{~}`, I suppose